# Upgrade mesa-utils Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, steam, opengl, mesa

I love Linux so I tend to play games on Linux.
So I install steam on ubuntu 18.04

The game I tried to play needs OpenGL 3.1 [see here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5629)
So, I did some search on the internet and I found [this](https://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-18-04-lts-users-can-now-install-mesa-18-1-1-to-improve-their-linux-gaming-521543.shtml)

After installing ppa and `sudo apt update && apt dist-upgrade` the package mesa-utils is still not updated
`apt search mesa` shows me "mesa-utils/bionic,now 8.4.0-1 amd64 [installed]"

Please suggest me how to update mesa-utils?

Comment: What do you suggest to install rather than `mesa-utils` so I can use **OpenGL 3.1**

Answer (score 0):

I did some more search and I found [this](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMDQ)
So basically my GPU can only support OpenGL 2.1